# What does %di specifier do in C programming?

Tags: c, complex-numbers, specifier

%d specifier inside the printf function means that we're going to display the variable as a decimal integer and %f specifier would display it as a float number and so on.
But what does %di specifier does ?

[I found this specifier in this program(C program to add, subtract, multiply and divide Complex Numbers, complex arithmetic)](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-perform-operations-complex-numbers)

For example,

```
printf("Division of two complex numbers = %d %di",temp1/temp3,temp2/temp3);
```

Comment: That's just a `%d`, immediately followed by an `i`, probably to indicate the imaginary part. Only the `%d` is the format specifier, the `i` printed literally

Comment: like if you write `printf("%di",a)` then first value of `a` will be printed then `i` (assuming `a` in an integer variable.)

Comment: Are `temp1  temp2 temp3` all `int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `temp/temp3` evaluates to 25 and `temp2/temp3` evaluates to 15, the line

```
printf("Division of two complex numbers = %d %di",temp1/temp3,temp2/temp3);
```

will print

```
Division of two complex numbers = 25 15i
```

The `i` in the above format specifier prints the letter `i`. The `%d` parts print the numbers. The sole purpose of using `i` in the above format specifier is to print the real and imaginary parts of a complex number in a more user friendly way.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specifier `"%di"`. So, it works as `"%d"` and after it you have a letter `"i"` (it is standard way to print imaginary part of complex values).

So when you have a line `printf("Sum of two complex numbers = %d + %di",c.real,c.img);` it works this way:

- It prints "Sum of two complex numbers = ",
- It prints value `c.real`,
- It prints " + ",
- It prints value `c.img`,
- And it prints `"i"`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as %di in C ! In fact %d has been used in the code for the integer! Since you are printing a complex number 
Such as

> 4 + 5i

You need to print an 'i immediately after you print 5 hence "%di" is used "%d" and i are seen seperately by the printf function!

Comment: "_are seen seperately by the compiler_": not by the compiler, but by the `printf` function.

Comment: ^ Yeah to be more appropriate! Edited

Answer (score 0):

There is no specifier "%di" in C. It just works normally as "%d" and after it you have a letter "i" printed. Example your output would look something like this:

```
int temp1=8;
int temp2=10;
int temp3=2;

printf("Division of two complex numbers = %d %di",temp1/temp3,temp2/temp3);
```

output:`Division of two complex numbers = 4 5i`